# inner join query in joomla

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

I want to fire one complex query in my joomla site. I have written below code for it.

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select('`chr`.`characteristic_id`,`chr`.`characteristic_value`,`prc`.`price_value`');
$query->from('`#___hikashop_product` AS `pdt`');
$query->join('inner', '`#__hikashop_variant` AS `vari` ON `pdt`.`product_id` = `vari`.`variant_characteristic_id`');
$query->join('inner', '`#__hikashop_characteristic` AS `chr` ON `vari`.`variant_characteristic_id` = `chr`.`characteristic_id`');
$query->join('inner', '`#__hikashop_price` AS `prc` ON `pdt`.`product_id` = `prc`.`price_product_id`');
$query->where('`pdt`.`product_id` = 68');
$db->setQuery($query);
```

Query is executing in my local mysql.
any help will be appreciated

Comment: Maybe the double quotes?

Comment: I don't know Joomla, but does your `$query` object really have methods `select()`, `from()` and `where()`?  Or, being part of the SQL command you're constructing, are those supposed to be part of the arguments to some other function?  You also **really** shouldn't be embedding your variables in the SQL command - use prepared statements instead!  If you don't know why, or what they are, read about [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com).

Comment: @MrCode : I dont know .. I actually dont know how to fire query in joomla. Query is running fine if I execute it in mysql

Comment: I never knew Joomla had those join/where methods, but I don't think I like it. Flat SQL is inifitely more readable!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this

```
$db->setQuery("Your query");
$result = $db->query();

//if you need the count
$rowcount = $db->getNumRows();

//if the result is multiple rows
$result_array = $db->loadAssocList() or $db->loadObjectList();

//if the result is single row you can use
$result = $db->loadAssoc() or $db->loadObject();
```

Answer (score 3):

To fire the query, all you need to do is:

```
$rows = $db->loadAssocList(); // or loadObjectList()
```

The above will put all of the rows into `$rows`

You can also fire the query without grabbing the rows with:

```
$db->query();
```

Comment: what should i do to echo query in page? is there any function for that? my query returns me empty set. If i run this on mysql, it gives me 13 rows..

Comment: Try `echo $db->getQuery()` to print it. Also check `echo $db->getErrorMsg();` to see if there was a MySQL error.